# Does it make sense to have a CORBA interface to a RESTful service?

Tags: rest, corba

Does it make sense to have a CORBA interface to a RESTful service? I've been asked to find out if a restful service can be made to have a corbaloc url instead of http/https url; this seemingly avoids the network overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **No.**

**Why?**

Corba is a complete middleware while REST is more way of providing data between webservices using http.
Thus, what shall a service do with a corbaloc uri then? What's the protocol to be used then?
IMHO it does not make any sense to use corbaloc for REST.

Corbaloc is made for corba (e.g., saying which version is used). A URL for REST isn't more complicated or longer.
E.g.,

```
corbaloc://host:port/object_id
```

vs

```
http://host:port/endpoint
```

I cannot see any advantage of using corbaloc here. For http/s the port could be omitted, for corbaloc rarely.